# How do I query for strings with spaces using dot notation in mongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a subobject in a mongo database with fields that contain spaces, something like:

```
{name: "John Doe", subdata: {"Field 1": "Something", "Field 2": "Something else"}}
```

From what I've been able to find, mongo allows the fields Field 1 and Field 2, but I haven't been able to find any indication of how to structure a query to look for subdata.Field 1. Is there a way I could search for Field 1 and Field 2 in my example, or should I restructure my data to get rid of white spaces?

Comment: Mongo tells me that that is incorrect JSON Notation which is the correct behaviour. If `Field 1` was rather `"Field 1"` etc, it is valid and query'able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know about pymongo, but many libraries for other languages offer object-document mapping functionality. I bet you'll have problems with this as well, because "Field 1" is an invalid identifier in every language I heard of.

My advice: get rid of whitespaces, you'll save a great amount of time in the future.

Comment: I took your advice and just dumped the whitespace for simplicity.

Answer (score 6):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you can just do:

```
db.test.find({ "subdata.Field 1" : 'Something' } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Space is a valid character for Mongo field names.

[**Restrictions on Field Names**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

> Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .) or [null characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (i.e. \0), and they must not start with a dollar sign (i.e. $).

So kind of lookup should work like a charm:

```
db.collection.find({"subdata.Field 1": {$exists: true}})
```